# Ubuntus (lib)ATLAS packages are only multi-threaded

Tags: 16.04, libraries

Before I file a bug, I would like to ask if anybody can confirm that the (lib)ATLAS packages (libatlas3-base) in Ubuntu (not limited to 16.04) are multi-threaded only? And, that there is no way to enable single-thread behavior (like using libsatlas, some distributions provide)?

The problem I have is that if I use the ubuntu-provided ATLAS libraries in am MPI program locally, in every MPI-process the ATLAS routines use the full number of available CPUs. This leads to massive overloading of the machine.

I think it would be very helpful for the purpose of simultaneously running multiple processes utilizing ATLAS to provide a single threaded variant of ATLAS in the Ubuntu packages.

Comment: I would suggest opening a bug on this against the packages asking for there to be a single-threaded variant made available.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's not possible to change the maximum number of threads used by Atlas at runtime, only at build time: http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#tnum

OpenBLAS can by setting `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` as an environment variable for instance.